# Data flow job's watermark lags a lot for unknown reason

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are running a Dataflow workflow which consumes from Kafka and writes snappy avro files to gcs using apache beam AvroIO write API. We have provisioned maximum of 13 workers which should handle 50k qps of incoming events. We use LogAppendTime for the kafka messages. The size of the each record is similar to each other. The window is 1 hour with the following trigger:

```
  Repeatedly
    .forever(
      AfterFirst.of(
        AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(50000),
        AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(5))
      )
    )
    .orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
```

Events are being produced to Kafka at the rate of 30k qps. After a while, the workers were only able to handle 25k qps with the data watermark lag increasing and behind by around 2 hours. So we updated the workflow assuming it would fix the issue. After updating, for the first one hour, it was able to process 45k qps, as expected, and data watermark was reducing. Past that, the CPU utilization of most of the workers dropped and  the qps dropped to 20k. This caused the data watermark lag to increase as events were being produced to Kafka at 30k qps rate.

On further investigation, we found that most of the worker's CPU utilization is low ranging from 15% to 20%, 2 of them have CPU utilization of 40% and one of them has 60% CPU utilization. From the logs, we see that the ones with higher CPU utilization write to gcs more often than the ones with low CPU utilization. We set the numShards to 26 assuming that the shards would be evenly distributed among the workers. However, it looks like data flow is assigning most of them to the same workers.

Details of the workflow:

job_id: 2018-05-08_10_39_57-9264166384462032078

numShards: 26

maxNumWorkers: 13

Comment: Is it possible that your pipeline has hot keys, preventing the work from being distributed? Note: data with the same key is processed serially, so if all of your data is grouped under the same key via GroupByKey, then you get poor parallelism.

If you continue to increase maxNumWorkers/numShards, are you seeing any improvements?

Comment: What is `numShards`? Are you doing a reshuffle? How many partitions does the Kafka topic have?

Comment: From internal metrics, it looks like you are mostly likely disk bound. If you have data skey as Alex mentioned earlier, that will limits disk IO throughput as well.

Comment: Numshards is the number of files being output for every trigger which we set it to 26. Kafka topic has 36 partitions. GroupByKey is used by Apache Batchload which groups elements based on their destination and the shard it goes to. For first record, a random shard is picked. Past that, round robin mechanism of choosing shards is done as seen https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BatchLoads.java#L455-L462
Records should be evenly distributed by BatchLoad writeShardedFiles & there should not be hot key.

Comment: You should probably @RaghuAngadi so he can see your last comment.

Comment: @revathy, could you file a support ticket. It allows better permission for people oncall to look at the job (job graph etc).

Comment: @RaghuAngadi The workers were limited by the number of IOPs that the persistent disk could perform. When we changed from standard to SSD persistent disk, didn't see the issue again :)

Answer (score 0):

Just not to leave the question unanswered. As commented by @revathy, the issue is fixed by changing from standard to SSD persistent disk, as the workers were limited by the number of IOPs that the persistent disk could perform.